# Windows 10 update - Boot problems after updates

Tags: windows-10

I used the mediacreationtool in order to update to Windows 10, and when it was done it worked correctly.

I did install Visual Studio, and it asked me to restart my laptop. Okay, that's all right.

So afterwards, it started doing some updates. Yes, okay, why not? Updates are always good, right?....

After the updates, it restarted. HOWEVER, it didn't boot Windows 10 anymore and all I get was 'Automatic Repair' and 'Diagnosting Problems'.

What is the problem? The reservation tool said my laptop was compatible. And now it somehow doesn't work and 2 friends doesn't have the problems I have. Can I solve it without installing Windows 10 again? Because if not, I might go over to Linux.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for your anger why not go back and edit it out.... makes people more likely to help

Comment: You're right @JoeTaylor changed.

Answer (score 0):

###### If you have usb with the Windows 7(or up) installer, try this:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to open command prompt.
- Type `bootrec /fixmbr`, enter
- Type `bootrec /fixboot`, enter
- Type `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, enter
- Type `chkdsk C: /f /r`, enter
- Close cmd and restart computer.

###### Or use [winRE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11) to get to Command Prompt, then:

- Type `bootrec /fixmbr`, enter
- Type `bootrec /fixboot`, enter
- Type `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, enter
- Type `chkdsk C: /f /r`, enter
- Close cmd and restart computer.